# Excess duplicated object in array + curve modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I have been trying to create an ammo belt by the combination of array and curve modifier for a cuboid as shown in the image, the rest of the belt outside of the cylinder (ammo box) is fine but why are there some excess cuboids inside the cylinder? I have positioned the cuboid at the initial vertex of the bezier curve already. What should I do to remove those excess cuboids as the whole array of object start to went off the path of the curve when I try to move the first cuboid. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Try moving your cube along one axis only to slide it along the curve. If that doesn't work, try switching your transform orientation from global to local or normal (at the bottom of the 3d view) and trying it again, either with the manipulator or by pressing G then the axis key twice.

Comment: Your first suggestion worked (moving along one axis only), thanks for your help!